# Dailymotion Video in listview Android

Tags: android, dailymotion-api

How do I show the list of "DAILYMOTION" videos in android?

Also how do I play them?

I am able to play single video, but I now want to show more than 25 videos in a list.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is more works than supposed to be on a simple stackoverflow question!

You can:

- list videos using Dailymotion API (documentation here https://developer.dailymotion.com/api)
- and then play them using the Dailymotion video player. Here you'll find the documentation about the Android Player SDK: https://developer.dailymotion.com/tools/sdks#sdk-android that is a thin wrapper around a WebView that allows to easily embed Dailymotion videos into your Android application. You can check the source code, documentation and sample app on the GitHub repo: https://github.com/dailymotion/dailymotion-sdk-android/tree/master.

There even is a sample app that may help you get started! https://github.com/dailymotion/dailymotion-sdk-android/tree/master/SampleApp